# discord.js v13 command handler of interactions failed

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I am trying to add interaction to my discord bot who already has a command and event handler. I followed the [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide) and adding the commands worked just fine. But now I am trying to do the [command handling](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html#individual-command-files) part, but it gives the error:

```
TypeError: command.execute is not a function
```

my code in index.js:

```
console.clear()

const fs = require('fs')

const { Collection } = require('discord.js');

const Client = require("./Structures/Client.js");

const config = require("./Data/config.json");

const client = new Client();

client.commands = new Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./src/iCommands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./iCommands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

client.on("interactionCreate", async interaction => {
    if(!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if(!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
});

client.start(config.token);
```

My code in deploy-commands.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./Data/config.json');

const commands = [];
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./src/iCommands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./iCommands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}
    
const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), { body: commands })
    .then(() => console.log('Succesfully registerd application commands.'))
    .catch(console.error);
```

and then for the commands itself, just the standard code given by the guide. I also tried it in a blank piece of code, and there it worked fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made some typo in the Directory name

```
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./src/iCommands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./iCommands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}
```

The folder that readed is in `./src/iCommands`. But the file that want to be accessed is in `./iCommands/`

It should be like this

```
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./src/iCommands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./src/iCommands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}
```

Also make sure you have write the code (for example ping.js) in the `./src/iCommands/ping.js` file. Avoid to leave it blank to prevent any error.

Your bot directory should be look more like this

[image: dir1]

also this for disambiguation

[image: dir2]